# "webdriver-manager update" Command shows error message in Protractor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, webdriver-manager

When I issue the command 
`webdriver-manager update` while starting my protractor script execution I see below error message:

> "Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:568:26)"

Answer (score 1):

Add proxy if your network behind proxy.  
`webdriver-manager update --proxy http://yourproxy:yourport`.

Also add proxy for `webdriver-manager start`.

If you don't like to type the proxy every time, you can add `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` Environment Variables.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are behind corporate firewall, Try below commands. It should work fine.

```
webdriver-manager update --ignore-ssl --proxy http://XXX.XXX.XXX:80
webdriver-manager start --ignore-ssl --proxy http://XXX.XXX.XXX:80
```

if both of them doesn't work. Try the below command as well.

```
 webdriver-manager update --proxy http://XXX.XXX.XXX:8000 --ignore_ssl --gecko false
```